# How to fix " Missing commit" in maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin?

Tags: maven

I have a project:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch 10.3 https://gitlab.orekit.org/orekit/orekit.git
```

and I have deleted a "src/test" folder there to build it without tests and I got error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin:1.2.10:extract-buildnumber (default) @ orekit ---
[ERROR] 
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RevWalkException: Walk failure.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.iterator (RevWalk.java:1231)
    at ru.concerteza.util.buildnumber.BuildNumberExtractor.countCommits (BuildNumberExtractor.java:142)
    at ru.concerteza.util.buildnumber.BuildNumberExtractor.extract (BuildNumberExtractor.java:55)
    at ru.concerteza.util.buildnumber.JGitBuildNumberMojo.execute (JGitBuildNumberMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing commit b63d56bedd68ad45b5dd6d0acedae8048cf61b8b
```

Could you tell me what it means, how to fix that and what is "maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin" for?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know enough about this specific issue, but maven is trying to look at older commits in that repository (that's what RevWalk usually does). The error message itself looks similar to https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/issues/96.